# Sonar Scanner not able to run scan on SonarQube 8.9 (Docker)

Tags: docker, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have setup SonarQube 8.9 on my local laptop using Docker image. I am able to launch the SonarQube server at http://localhost:9000/. Every thing works good from Browser.  But if I try to run sonar scanner I get this error. Any help is appreciated

```
 C:\repo>sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" -Dsonar.login="key"
[18:00:22] Starting analysis...
[18:00:22] Checking if executable exists: C:\Users\shashk\.sonar\native-sonar-scanner\sonar-scanner-4.5.0.2216-windows\bin\sonar-scanner.bat
[18:00:22] Platform binaries for SonarScanner found. Using it.
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Users\shashk\.sonar\native-sonar-scanner\sonar-scanner-4.5.0.2216-windows\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\repo\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarScanner 4.5.0.2216
INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\shashk\.sonar\cache
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 5:00.631s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/20M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:73)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:286)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:51)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$AbstractSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:389)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$UnknownLengthSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:529)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.java:286)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.select(RealBufferedSource.java:100)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:467)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:181)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:100)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
        ... 19 more
ERROR:
```

Comment: Can you include information about how you are starting your sonarqube server?  Also, can you confirm that you're running the scan on your localhost.

Comment: @kthompso I have started my SonarQube Server with docker using this command - docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube      Yes I am running scanner on my local host machine. This is the command I am using to run scan sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" -Dsonar.login="b4dd2db3e54c637a25bd516564bfd1742c9108a2"

Comment: Try to add `-Dsonar.verbose=true` to the sonar-scanner invocation and inspect the output. It should give you what exact URL it is trying to reach. I would then check with `curl -v <url>`  whether it is reachable from the command line.